# Web server hanging. I have no idea why

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm writing a very tiny, very sh*tty web server just for fun. It was working fine with GET requests or returning a 404. And worked very briefly working with POST requests. And now it just hangs on any POST request.

Here is the relevant bit of code. As you can see I put in some logging to both System.out and to a file. The logging to System.out works, but the logging to file never happens.  If I remove the logging to file, it still hangs on the line after System.out log.  I included the few lines previous so you can see that it is the exact same code as returning a 404. 404 works, but POST doesn't. This is using a ServerSocket. I'm at a complete loss at this point. Would appreciate any insight.

Edit: Have included the main and sendResponse methods in case there is anything in there that might be causing this.

Edit #2: Ima just post the whole thing.

```
package beerio;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class Beerio {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket client = serverSocket.accept()) {
                    handleClient(client);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                    e.printStackTrace(pw);
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("errorlog.txt", true));
                    writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    writer.append(sw.toString());
                    writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    writer.close();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void handleClient(Socket client) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        //make request into string. this only parses until the first blank line
        StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while (!(line = br.readLine()).isBlank()) {
            requestBuilder.append(line + "\r\n");
        }        
        //split string and parse into request info
        String request = requestBuilder.toString();
        String[] requestsLines = request.split("\r\n");
        String[] requestLine = requestsLines[0].split(" ");
        String method = requestLine[0];
        String path = requestLine[1];
        String version = requestLine[2];
        String host = requestsLines[1].split(" ")[1];

        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int h = 2; h < requestsLines.length; h++) {
            String header = requestsLines[h];
            headers.add(header);
        }
        //rest of request contains post info. parse that here
        if(method.equals("POST")) {
            String parameters;
            parameters = br.readLine();
            String[] temp = parameters.split("&");
            String[][] params = new String[temp.length][2];
            for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
                params[i][0] = temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("="));
                params[i][1] = temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("=")+1);
            }
        }
        Path filePath = getFilePath(path);
        if (method.equals("GET")) { 
            System.out.println("doGet");
            if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
                // file exist
                String contentType = guessContentType(filePath);
                sendResponse(client, "200 OK", contentType, Files.readAllBytes(filePath));
            } else {
                // 404
                byte[] notFoundContent = "<h1>Not found :(</h1>".getBytes();
                sendResponse(client, "404 Not Found", "text/html", notFoundContent);
            }
        } else if(method.equals("POST")){
            byte[] postContent = "<h1>POST Failed Successfully</h1>".getBytes();
            sendResponse(client, "200 OK", "text/html", postContent);
        }
    }

    private static void sendResponse(Socket client, String status, String contentType, byte[] content) throws IOException {
        OutputStream clientOutput = client.getOutputStream();
        clientOutput.write(("HTTP/1.1 " + status+"/r/n").getBytes());
        clientOutput.write(("ContentType: " + contentType + "\r\n").getBytes());
        clientOutput.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        clientOutput.write(content);
        clientOutput.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
        clientOutput.flush();
        client.close();
    }

    private static Path getFilePath(String path) {
        if ("/".equals(path)) {
            path = "\\index.html";
        }

        return Paths.get("C:\\Users\\shawn\\beerio\\beerio\\tmp\\www", path);
    }

    private static String guessContentType(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        return Files.probeContentType(filePath);
    }

}
```

Comment: This might need more information, as it could be an issue inside the `sendResponse` method or how you handle incoming connections threading wise, with the current information it's too ambiguous for me at least

Comment: @Ben Thanks for looking. I did update with the sendResponse and main methods. Fairly sure the problem isn't in the main as it will sometimes drop socket on a GET and have to reload, but a POST will never make it through.

Comment: I haven't read any of this, so am just putting this link out as a guess: [mre]